# Stop closing result on space

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to stop closing the results span if the user try to add a space between word (Push on space).

I build this select from by symfony FormType, but I want to get the class in js and make the changement.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) {
            console.log("CODE : "+e.keyCode);
            if(e.keyCode === 32){
                console.log('TEST');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
 });
```

So the idea is to stop hide the div is user try to add spaces. Examples :

"Test" ---> works fine

"test_test" ---> works fine

"Test test" ---> not work because this tag has spaces, the span is hidden and input has only the first word, and I want to prevent that

Comment: What is the result span? The results selectables div? Why is it closing for you when you type space? This is not the normal behavior. Please explain your problem further or create a jsfiddle of your problem.

Comment: I update the code, can you check please ?

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions =)